# Javascript function does not execute after certain line

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am currently creating a Dapp for Ethereum using Truffle and testrpc. On our register page, I have a button that signs the user up with all the information entered. However, when the button is clicked, the register function in the app.js javascript file is called, but does not execute passed the `var regi = Register.deployed();` line. I am gettig an error in the console on the webpage as seen below. I have attempted to debug this for hours but with no success.

[image: Console Errors]

This is the app.js file. The register function is the function that takes the data inputted and sends it to the Register Contract.

The code below that is the index.html file. The `<button id="confirmsignup" onclick="register()">Sign Up</button>` tag is the button that calls register() in app.js when clicked.

Finally, the last one is the code for the Contract Register that sets up an account for the user.

```js
var accounts;
var account;
var balance;
var logged;

function setStatus(message) {
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  status.innerHTML = message;
};

function refreshBalance() {
  var meta = MetaCoin.deployed();

  meta.getBalance.call(account, {from: account}).then(function(value) {
    var balance_element = document.getElementById("balance");
    balance_element.innerHTML = value.valueOf();
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    setStatus("Error getting balance; see log.");
  });
};

function sendCoin() {
  var meta =  MetaCoin.deployed();

  var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value);
  var receiver = document.getElementById("receiver").value;

  setStatus("Initiating transaction... (please wait)");

  meta.sendCoin(receiver, amount, {from: account}).then(function() {
    setStatus("Transaction complete!");
    refreshBalance();
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    setStatus("Error sending coin; see log.");
  });
  getAccountBalance();
};

function getAccountBalance() {
  var meta = MetaCoin.deployed();

  var balance = meta.getBalance(msg.sender);

}

function register() {

  var nickname = document.getElementById("userid").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var rePassword = document.getElementById("reenterpassword").value;
  var addr = document.getElementById("ethereumAddress").value;

  logged = true;
  var regi = Register.deployed();


  web3.eth.defaultAccount = addr;

  if (password == rePassword) {
    regi.setAccountInfo(nickname, email, password, addr).then(function() {
      console.log("The account was setup with the appropriate details");
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
    alert("Congratulations! You registered an account with Cogitaire!");
  } else {
    alert("The passwords do not match!");
  }

};

function displayInfo() {
  var display = Register.deployed();

  var idCheck = document.getElementById("idForCheck").value;
  if (logged) {
    console.log("The user is logged: " + logged);
    display.getNickname.call(web3.eth.defaultAccount).then(function(value) {
      document.getElementById('nickshow').innerHTML = value;
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
    display.getEmail.call(web3.eth.defaultAccount).then(function(value) {
      document.getElementById('emailshow').innerHTML = value;
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
  } else {
    alert("You are not logged in! Please log in to see your user information or enter address to see someone elses user information");
  }
};

function logOff() {
  var log = Register.deployed();

  logged = false;
  alert("You are now logged off!");

  web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0xda9c209aafee487d729866bc0d58223a62bfe383';

};

function showLogin() {
  registerSection.style.display = 'none';
  loginSection.style.display = 'block';
};

function showRegister() {
  registerSection.style.display = 'block';
  loginSection.style.display = 'nice';
};

window.onload = function() {
  var Web3 = require([web3]);
  // create an instance of web3 using the HTTP provider.
  // in mist web3 is already available, so check first if its available before instantiating
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    var web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8080"));
  }
  //var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8080"));
  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
    if (err != null) {
      alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
      return;
    }

    if (accs.length == 0) {
      alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
      return;
    }

    getAddress.call().then(function(value) {
      web3.eth.defaultAccount = value;
    });

    accounts = accs;
    account = accounts[0];

    refreshBalance();
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Cogitare</title>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>

    <script src="/javascripts/bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="javascripts/require.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container topnav">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img class="navbar-brand topnav" src="img/BIRD2thin.jpg" alt="can't display rn">

            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a style="color:white;" href="./newProjectInfo.html">Submit An Idea</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a style="color:white;" href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a style="color:white;" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a style="color:white;" href="#signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-modal-lg">Sign In/Register</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>


    <!-- Header -->
    <a name="about"></a>
    <div class="intro-header">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="intro-message">
                        <h1>Where ideas take flight</h1>
                        <h3>ejofaojwefojwejoaewoj</h3>
                        <hr class="intro-divider">
                        <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
                            <li>
                                <a href="google.com" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"></i> <span class="network-name">Discover Projects</span></a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

    </div>


    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" style="color:#777">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="footer-menu-divider">&sdot;</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about" style="color:#777">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="footer-menu-divider">&sdot;</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#services" style="color:#777">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="footer-menu-divider">&sdot;</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#contact" style="color:#777">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="copyright text-muted small">Copyright &copy; Your Company 2014. All Rights Reserved</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>



<div class="modal fade bs-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <br>
        <div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
            <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a style="color:black" href="#signin" data-toggle="tab">Sign In</a></li>
              <li class=""><a style="color:black" href="#signup" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
              <li class=""><a style="color:black" href="#why" data-toggle="tab">Show User Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="why">
        <p>Click this button to show information about you!</p>
        <!--<p></p><br> Please contact <a mailto:href="theoluan@gmail.com"></a>theoluan@gmail.com</a> with questions.</p>-->
        <button id="display" onclick="displayInfo()">Display Information</button>
        <br><label id="nickshow">test</label></br>
        <br><label id="emailshow">test</label></br>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="signin">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
            <!-- Sign In Form -->

            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="reenterpassword">Ethereum Address</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="ethereumAddress" class="form-control" name="ethid" type="text" placeholder="2309482309" class="input-large" required="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="theo@theo.com" class="input-medium" required="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="passwordinput">Password</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input required="" id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-medium">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
              <div class="controls">
                <button id="signin" name="signin" class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!--Register-->

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="signup">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>

            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="reenterpassword">Ethereum Address</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="ethereumAddress" class="form-control" name="ethid" type="text" placeholder="2309482309" class="input-large" required="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="theo@theo.com" class="input-large" required="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="userid">Nickname:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="userid" name="userid" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="theo" class="input-large" required="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
                <em>1-8 Characters</em>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="reenterpassword">Re-Enter Password:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="reenterpassword" class="form-control" name="reenterpassword" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
            <br>


            <!-- Button -->
                <!--<button id="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success" onclick="register()">Sign Up</button>-->
                <button id="confirmsignup" onclick="register()">Sign Up</button>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <center>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

```
contract Register {

    //address public userAddr;

    struct User {
        address userAddress;
        string nickname;
        string email;
        string password;
        bool isLoggedIn;
    }
    mapping(address => User) users;
    address public creator;
    //bool public isLoggedIn;

    function Register() {
        creator = msg.sender;
    }


    function setAccountInfo(string nickname, string email, string password, address addr) {
        users[addr].nickname = nickname;
        users[addr].email = email;
        users[addr].password = password;
    }

    function getNickname(address addr) returns (string) {
        return users[addr].nickname;
    }

    function getEmail(address addr) returns (string) {
        return users[addr].email;
    }

    function getAddress() constant returns (address) {
        return creator;
    }

    function setLoggedStatus(address addr, bool condition) {
        users[addr].isLoggedIn = condition;
    }

    function getLoggedStatus(address addr) constant returns (bool success) {
        return users[addr].isLoggedIn;
    }

}
```

I can't figure out why the code does not execute after the javascript line Register.deployed(). Any help that could possibly lead me in the right direction would be helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: javascript tends to stop after uncaught errors

Comment: the error suggests that `Web3.providers` is undefined ... please add the errors to the question, rather than a link to a screen capture of the errors

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind! Sorry, I am just a beginner in coding since this is the first Dapp I am creating. When I do try to set the provider with 
var Web3 = require([web3]);
var web3 = Web3.setProvider(newWeb3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8080'));
I get the error Cannot read property 'setProvider' of undefined

Comment: It seems Web3 is not correctly linked. Could this line be the issue? `var Web3 = require([web3]);`